# Code won't compile for WeMos D1 but works fine for Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

Code won't compile for WeMos D1 but works fine for Arduino Uno.

I get the error

```
error: 'A1' was not declared in this scope
```

```cpp
#include "HX711.h"

HX711 scale(A1, A0);// parameter "gain" is ommited; the default value 128 is used by the library

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);//2280
    scale.set_scale(1810.f); //// this value is obtained by calibrating the scale with known weights
    scale.tare();
}

void loop() {
    Serial.print("\n");
    Serial.print(scale.get_units(), 1);
    scale.power_down(); // put the ADC in sleep mode
    delay(500);
    scale.power_up();
}
```

Comment: ESP8266 has only one analog pin which can't be used as a digital pin.

Comment: answer below would be marked as resolution.

Answer (score 0):

From the [reference doc of the ESP8266 Arduino repo](https://web.archive.org/web/20160406094803/https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/doc/reference.md#analog-input):

> ESP8266 has a single ADC channel available to users. It may be used
> either to read voltage at ADC pin, or to read module supply voltage
> (VCC).
>
> To read external voltage applied to ADC pin, use analogRead(A0). Input
> voltage range is 0 — 1.0V.

So A1 is not defined as well.